# Dungeons & Dragons starring Dragons: Which edition would work best for dragon PCs?

Tags: game-recommendation, dungeons-and-dragons

Next year's theme for our local gaming 'Con is "Year of the Dragon", and I've had inspiration to prepare and run a "Dungeons & Dragons starring the Dragons" scenario. While I have a fairly varied amount of GM experience, my knowledge of D&D specifically is... somewhat limited.

I am looking for a recommendation on which version of D&D would most suitable to running full-sized True Dragons and recommendations for books/supplements to pick up (beyond the obvious players/DM/monster handbooks for whichever edition I go with).

Since this will be running at a 'Con, the best system would be:

- Beginner-friendly (will be open to players of any experience level);
- Able to support dragon PCs using RAW with minimal fudging/house ruling;
- Reasonably streamlined, especially for combat;
- Easily available (DriveThruRPG seems to have a fairly comprehensive selection of all editions from what I can see)

Thank-you very much in advance.  If anything needs clarification please feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Are you looking for a system which will allow a party of Adventurers and Dragons to work together, or will every PC have to select their race as a type of Dragon?

Comment: A full party of dragons. There'll be plenty of opportunities to play humans, etc., in other games!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Advanced Dungeons & Dragons 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition**

[Council of Wyrms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560768576) had rules for players to roleplay as a dragon and dragon themed characters. However, this material is very dated, and roleplaying consists of years at a time rather than days at a time.

**Dungeons & Dragons 3.x Edition**

[Draconomicon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786928840), [Races of Dragon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786939133), [Dragon Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786939362), [Savage Species](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926481) all give rules for players to play as dragon and as dragonkind. Being an actual dragon will not result in a very powerful character due to racial hit dice and level adjustments. But if everyone is suffering the same restraint, it will be balanced and could be fun. Even Wyrmlings are born intelligent.

**Personal Disclaimer**

I am unaware, personally, of 4<sup>th</sup> Edition or 5<sup>th</sup> Edition rulesets that would allow a dragon to be played.

---

**Sample Monster Class (D&D 3.x):**

Scribd: [Juvenile Black Dragon (17 Level Monster Class)](https://www.scribd.com/doc/269636649/Black-Dragon-Juvenile-Monster-Class)

Comment: Re: Racial/level adjustments: I'm not worried against being balanced against a Lv5 half-elf ranger or anything, just that the PC dragons should be reasonably balanced with respect to each other so that nobody steals anybody's thunder. Or flame/acid/cold.

Comment: I am pretty certain there is no official material for playing a dragon PC in 4E. I don't expect there is any in 5E, either, mainly due to it being a niche requirement to have monstrous PCs, and the system is still pretty new.

Comment: Worth mentioning, that Dragon Magazine 320 and 332 presented racial classes respectively for metallic and chromatic true dragons.